# Can i use a DefaultBinder to do dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

i am trying to implement dependency injection for our custom ModelBinders. Right now i have

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // removed IoC configuration code

        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CastleWindsorModelBinder(this.container, ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder);

        // removed configuration code
    }

    public class CastleWindsorModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;
    private readonly IModelBinder fallback;

    public CastleWindsorModelBinder(IWindsorContainer container, IModelBinder fallback)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.fallback = fallback;
    }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var binder = (IModelBinder)this.container.Resolve(
                    bindingContext.ModelType.FullName, typeof (IModelBinder));

            return binder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
        catch (ComponentNotFoundException)
        {
            return fallback.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
    }
```

but i'am not sure if this will result in overall poor performance. Can anybody share his own experience with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) already has this. See the [source code](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6aa25407de83#src%2fMvcContrib.Castle%2fWindsorModelBinder.cs) and [tests](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6aa25407de83#src%2fMVCContrib.UnitTests%2fBinders%2fWindsorModelBinderTester.cs).